# calculate different trips over two subsequent month in a SQL query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a simple table that contains trips over different dates.

| trip_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 160320 | 2017-12-31 20:40:25 UTC | 2017-12-31 20:45:25 UTC |
| 160321 | 2018-01-12 21:01:51 UTC | 2018-01-12 22:01:51 UTC |

I simply want to create a SQL query that shows these fields.

- year
- month
- trips_this_month,
- trips_previous_month
- difference_from_previous_month (count_this_month - count_previous_month)
- is_increased (is a boolean column that is true if we saw an increase, false
  otherwise)
  Update:
  I could wrap up my head and write a simple query to obtain them, but I still feel I can optimize this query. Any help will be appreciated.

```sql
    SELECT
    year,
    month,
    trips_this_month,
    trips_previous_month,
    case when difference_from_previous_month < 0 then false else true end as is_increased
FROM    
(SELECT    
    year,
    month,
    number_of_trips AS trips_this_month,
    LAG(number_of_trips,1,0) over (order by year,month) AS trips_previous_month,    
    number_of_trips - LAG(number_of_trips,1,0) OVER(order by year,month) AS difference_from_previous_month,    
    FROM(
        SELECT EXTRACT(Month FROM start_date) AS month,
               EXTRACT(Year FROM start_date) AS year,
               COUNT(*) as number_of_trips
               FROM a_table
    group by  month ,year
    )
    order by year, month
    limit 100
)
```

But I could not help myself to do more. I appreciate with further helps to complete it.

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: Your sample data is not _subsequent month_ . Also, your attempted query is just taking `month` without any condition of `year` so `2017-01` will get count together with `2018-01`.

Comment: @FanoFN Thanks , I updated my my question. I need to optimize the select-in-select query. any suggestion?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to return result of the subsequent month even there are no trips made that month, right?

Comment: @FanoFN yes I need to calculate for all months, the problem I am facing in above query, is that I had to use alias 'as' to name the column, but I could not use them at the same SELECT query , so I had to pass the result as a subsequent SELECT query to another SELECT. This looks not optimized but I don't know other ways unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a self-join to compare current and previous months aggregations using a normalized first-day of month date:

```sql
WITH sub AS (
    SELECT 
       DATE_SUB(
           DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(start_date), INTERVAL 1 DAY), 
           INTERVAL 1 MONTH
       ) AS month_year,
       COUNT(*) AS number_of_trips
    FROM a_table
    GROUP BY month_year
), calc AS (
    SELECT
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM curr.month_year) AS year,
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM curr.month_year) AS month,
       COALESCE(curr.number_of_trips, 0) AS trips_this_month,
       COALESCE(prev.number_of_trips, 0) AS trips_previous_month
    FROM sub AS curr
    LEFT JOIN sub AS prev
        ON prev.month_year = DATE_SUB(curr.month_year, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
)

SELECT
    year,
    month,
    trips_this_month,
    trips_previous_month,
    trips_this_month - trips_previous_month AS difference_from_previous_month,
    (trips_this_month - trips_previous_month) > 0 AS is_increased
FROM calc
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am trying your answer. I am using Google Cloud Big Query. I am new to Google Big Query. Unfortunately It does not support must of the functions

Comment: I see you updated the tags. This answered assumed MySQL. However, most of the date functions appear supported. See [BigQuery Date Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions). Though I did replace `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` with `EXTRACT`. See edit.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I updated the tag, just after realized BigQuery also has a tag here and set yours as answer. Though  I have a question. I compared the performance and realized not much difference in response time. Not sure if we can optimize it further

Answer (score 0):

**This is a MySQL answer and was posted before OP change the tag.** 
I don't work with Bigquery so I'm not sure how much of my answer need to be tweaked before it can be used in Bigquery. What I do know is the I've tested OP's original query together with the query from accepted answer on MySQL server and it works so I assume my suggested (MySQL) answer doesn't need a lot of tweaking for it to work in Bigquery.

---

Try this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
SELECT MIN(start_date) minstdt, MAX(start_date) maxstdt FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT minstdt+INTERVAL 1 MONTH, maxstdt FROM cte 
       WHERE minstdt+INTERVAL 1 MONTH <= maxstdt )
       
SELECT year,
       month,
       number_of_trips,
       number_of_trips-IFNULL(prev_month_number_of_trips,0) AS This_month_vs_prev_month,
       IF(number_of_trips > prev_month_number_of_trips,1,0) AS Is_increased
FROM
(SELECT
     YEAR(cte.minstdt) AS year,
     MONTH(cte.minstdt) AS month,
     SUM(CASE WHEN start_date IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS number_of_trips,
     LAG(SUM(CASE WHEN start_date IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)) 
         OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(cte.minstdt), MONTH(cte.minstdt)) AS prev_month_number_of_trips
    FROM cte 
LEFT JOIN mytable 
 ON YEAR(cte.minstdt)=YEAR(start_date) 
  AND MONTH(cte.minstdt)=MONTH(start_date) 
GROUP BY year, month) V
ORDER BY year, month;
```

1. I've used recursive common table expression (`cte`) to generate date based on the minimum and maximum date appeared in `start_date` of the table.
2. I've replaced `EXTRACT()` with `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` functions to make is slightly shorter.
3. I `LEFT JOIN` the `cte` with the data table.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e86465f8f05b834347c2ae6e80cf8fad)

See if you can work with this.